# My infix is smoking dead, my whole is in your head

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, affix-riddle

> My prefix is for sure a lie.
> My suffix is for sure alive.
> My infix is smoking dead.
> My whole is in your head.

<sub>*Note: the "in your head" here is not referring to anyone; it means if one has it at all, it would be in their head.*</sub>

Comment: I don't have a (w)hole in my head ...

Comment: On the contrary, you have several.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think it could be

> Shame

Reasons:

My prefix is for sure a lie.

> A sham (**sham**e) is an instance of a lie, except of course when you are talking about pillow covers.

My suffix is for sure alive.

> I (sha**me**) would have to be alive to be typing this answer.

My infix is smoking dead.

> Ham (s**ham**e) is smoked and obviously dead.

My whole is in your head.

> Shame exists in a person's mind.